# How to assign keyboard shortcuts for very specific commands in OneNote 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-onenote-2013

How could I assign a keyboard shortcut for very specific commands in OneNote 2013?

For example:
I need to assign a keyboard shortcut for a specific text style [(Bold)+(Underline)+(FontSize:13)+(Color:Red)] to be "Alt+4". When I click "Alt+4", the text style changes to [(Bold)+(Underline)+(FontSize:13)+(Color:Red)].

Another example:
I need to assign a keyboard shortcut for another specific text style [(NotBold)+(NotUnderline)+(Italic)+(FontSize:8)+(Color:Yellow)+(HighlighColor:Black)] to be "Alt+5". When I click "Alt+5", the text style changes to [(NotBold)+(NotUnderline)+(Italic)+(FontSize:8)+(Color:Yellow)+(HighlighColor:Black)].

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done directly but it can be achieved for example with use of [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) tool.

1. In OneNote, find out and write down sequence of keys* needed to perform the action.
2. Pick suitable keyboard shortcut for launching your key sequence.
3. Add a macro to AutoHotKey to send the sequence you collected in step **1** when you press shortcut chosen in step **2**. ([see example of 4 macros for such tasks](https://superuser.com/a/1045933/287473))

*) you can also use mouse clicks into desired position relative to top left corner of the window, but actions triggered by keystrokes are simpler to maintain